# Whats the difference between implementation and implementation group in Gradle?

Tags: gradle

In Gradle is there a difference between these 2?

```
implementation 'com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc8:21.1.0.0'

implementation group: 'com.oracle.database.jdbc', name: 'ojdbc8', version: '21.1.0.0'
```

If not is there a preference between one or another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically the same thing but called in a different (overloaded) way. First is a single string arg method which is parsed for its parts, second is a multi argument method where the parts are passed.

You can think of it like these pseudo code methods:

```
implementation(String dependency){}
implementation(String group, String name, String version){}
```